How to setup the follow path animation and also be able to control the speed and finesses?
How to setup the follow path animation (with constraints) and also be able to control the speed and finesses in the graph editor?
Currently, my animation runs for a 100 frames, follows a spiral (a curve spiral) and begins at frame 0. After frame 100, it flies away to infinity. I fixed this by clicking "Clamp" under curve animation settings
In blender 3.X, I remember by adding keyframes for evaluation time you could dictate when your object would stop at any point on the curve. You also had graph editor curves and could modify the movement itself.

Don't click on the Animate Path of the constraint, if you did, select the curve, open the Graph Editor, open the N panel > Modifiers and close the Generator modifier. Now you can animate with the Evaluation Time of the curve.
